# Date conversion form string dd/mm/yy is failing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a SQL Server date in the format of `dd/mm/yy` in a `varchar` column. I am trying to convert this string to date but getting

> Msg 241, Conversion failed when converting date/time from character string.

I have tried `CAST()`, `TRY_CAST()`, `TRY_CONVERT()`, `CONVERT`, `PARSE()`, `TRY_PRASE()`. None of them is working.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @d varchar(50) = '13/09/22'

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @d, 103) -- I have tried different formats to no avail.
```

Also I have tried casting as below

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(@d AS datetime) -- Tried datetime2 as well, but all failing.
```

If I change the day part to < 12, the conversions work. Which means SQL Server is somehow interpreting this as `mm/dd/yy`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `CONVERT()` works if you use the correct mask:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '13/09/22', 3);  -- 2022-09-13 00:00:00.000
```

The problem is that mask `103` assumes a 4 digit year, not a 2 digit year.  For a 2 digit year date in `dd/mm/yy` format, use mask `3`.

Comment: Not OP's fault, but I'm finding these two-digit years triggering...